# Make a git repository use other credentials than others on the same session (using Tortoise)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Is it possible to have one repository use a different set of credentials for pushing than others on the same machine, with the same session?

Use case: I am using a friend's computer, my friend contributes to project A using wincred session-wide, and I would like to contribute to project B without messing up his computer (possibly using wincred repository-wide). I trust my friend and his computer with my password on origin

I am using an up-to-date tortoise git 2.5 with git for windows 2.14 and wincred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second repo, you can either:

- enable [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) (after installing it), and use as an https URL: https://yourlogin@server.com/auser/gitrepo

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://yourlogin@server.com/auser/gitrepo
  git ls-remote
  ```

That will attempts to contact  https://yourlogin@server.com and will ask (and cache) your credentials.

- or you could switch to SSH (no more "manager"). You would then need to have a `~/.ssh/config` [correctly configured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806561/6309) (provided you can/have register(ed) your SSH public key on the server.