# authorisation error adding remote git repo with Ionic project

Tags: git, github, ionic-framework, ssh

Ionic Pro uses git to get access to the code you write in order to clone it in their cloud service - This is done so they can build your app on your behalf. An extract from their documentation:

```
Ionic Pro uses git to manage new app builds, push app updates, and more.
Before using Ionic Pro's git workflow, you must add a valid SSH key to your 
account.

Ionic Pro's git service is not a replacement for your source code management 
service of choice, such as GitHub or GitLab.
```

I would like to draw attention to the line: `Before using Ionic Pro's git workflow, you must add a valid SSH key to your account.`. Ionic is nice enough help you with this if you do not have one already and generate one for you and link it up to your account, which I did. So thus far I can do some work and then commit and push my changes to the ionic git (to start the cloud build) using `git push ionic master`; no issues.

I am now done prototyping and want to start serious development and add the project to my own Github repo. So i tried running `git remote add origin git@github.com:AccountName/AppName.git`. This executed without a problem. However, when I tried to run `git push -u origin master`, i get the error `fatal: Authentication Failed`. Since Ionic setup the repo, it also setup the SSH keys used for authentication, but I have no idea how that process actually works. Currently my git bash environment is setup with my Github account set to my username and password, but I dont know how to link this SSH based repo to my Github username:password based repo. I used Git Bash and copied my public SSH Key into my GitHub SSH Keys:

[image]

And this is also the only public SSH key on my machine:

[image]

[image]

However I am still getting this error if I try to run `git push -u origin master`:

[image]

Comment: Yes. You need to add your public key to your github account.

Comment: I tried copying that key over just the way it is, but i get the error "Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'"

Comment: Did you copy the contents of the public key? Double check against [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Comment: Public key? Sorry I'm not sure where ti find it.

Comment: Did you read the instructions I linked to?

Comment: Found it! Sorry it was a bit tucked away

Comment: No problem. Just doubled check that you’ve created the ssh key and have added it to github.

Comment: Thanks. Got the key and successfully added the key to my Github Account - Still no dice when I ry to push to remote. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I am still getting this error if I try to run git push -u origin master:

That is because your SSH URL does not take advantage of your ssh/config file, which does reference the `ssh/ionic/private_key` path.

That config path should have an `Host` entry, say `Host ionic`.
In that case, modify your SSH url:

```
git remote set-url origin ionic:AccountName/AppName.git
```

(not `git@github.com` here: everything is specified in `ssh/config`, under the `Host` entry, as [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806561/6309))