# GITBash CMD Error while opening

Tags: git, github

git Bash cmd error is showing in my terminal when I opened it.
Please provide the necessary actions to solve it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If none of the suggestions in "[Cygwin/Git error cygheap base mismatch detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48195349/6309)" are working, a good test is to reference Git in a simplified PATH.

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Make sure to reference in '`G`' the [latest Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) you can extract anywhere you want: [`PortableGit-2.16.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.16.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.16.2-64-bit.7z.exe), assuming you are on a Windows 64 bits.

Then, in that CMD session, try `git bash` again.