# How to update pywin32 automatically?

Tags: python, github, pip, pywin32

As I understand, one cannot use pip to install/upgrade `pywin32`, though `pip install -U pypiwin32` is a workaround.

`pywin32` is now hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases). I know very little of `git` but know that it works with binary files. Is there a way to programmatically upgrade the `pywin32` binary? That is, say `pywin32` v221 is installed with Python v.3.6 (64bit), the program should check against the latest (v223) on GitHub and download the `pywin32-223.win-amd64-py3.6.exe` and install it. So far, I can only think of a web-scraping-like script that compares the installed version with the latest version on the web and act accordingly. I wonder whether there's a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something crucial, otherwise (almost) every statement / assumption in the question seems incorrect:

1. It **is** possible to install / upgrade [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) using *PIP*
2. [GitHub](https://github.com) is used to host the **source code** (mainly). The assets there are Mark Hammond's *Win* installers (since *PyWin32* was hosted on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net) - long before *PIP* was born), I suppose they are only built for backward compatibility.
   There is a way to (build and) install directly from *GitHub* (or any other *URL*): [[SO]: pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20101834/4788546)
3. *PIP* doesn't download the *PyWin32* binary, but *.whl* (*wheel*) packages from [[PyPI]: Links for pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywin32)

In order to demo all the above, I created a *VirtualEnv*, and based on that, a series of steps:

- *Python* and *PIP* executables locations / versions
- *PIP* test (list *PyWin32* version using *PIP*) - no output (no *PyWin32* installed)
- *PyWin32* download and *URL* display
- *PyWin32* install (an older version to test upgrade later)
- *PIP* test
- *PyWin32* test (list *PyWin32* version using *PyWin32*)
- *PyWin32* upgrade
- *PIP* test
- *PyWin32* test

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py36x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049398198> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> where python pip
> c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x64_test\Scripts\python.exe
> c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x64_test\Scripts\pip.exe
>
> [prompt]> python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
> 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> [prompt]> pip -V
> pip 9.0.3 from c:\work\dev\venvs\py36x64_test\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
>
> [prompt]> :: PIP test
>
> [prompt]> pip list 2>nul | findstr pywin32
>
> [prompt]> pip download -vvv pywin32 2>nul | findstr /i download
>   Downloading pywin32-223-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (9.0MB)
>   Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/9f/9d/f4b2170e8ff5d825cd4398856fee88f6c70c60bce0aa8411ed17c1e1b21f/pywin32-223-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=2d211288ee000b6ec5d37436bcbe8a43 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywin32/)
> Successfully downloaded pywin32
>
> [prompt]> pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/be/25/0e0c568456b77ce144dd2b8799f915b046ffa1cd922771d214e4be05bca2/pywin32-222-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=94a9a3782081e14973c5ae448957d530 2>nul
> Collecting pywin32==222 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/be/25/0e0c568456b77ce144dd2b8799f915b046ffa1cd922771d214e4be05bca2/pywin32-222-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=94a9a3782081e14973c5ae448957d530
>   Downloading pywin32-222-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (9.0MB)
>     100% |################################| 9.0MB 135kB/s
> Installing collected packages: pywin32
> Successfully installed pywin32-222
>
> [prompt]> :: PIP test
>
> [prompt]> pip list 2>nul | findstr pywin32
> pywin32 (222)
>
> [prompt]> :: PyWin32 test
>
> [prompt]> python -c "import win32api as wapi;print(wapi.GetFileVersionInfo(wapi.__file__, \"\\\\\")[\"FileVersionLS\"] >> 16)"
> 222
>
> [prompt]> pip install -U pywin32 2>nul
> Collecting pywin32
>   Using cached pywin32-223-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
> Installing collected packages: pywin32
>   Found existing installation: pywin32 222
>     Uninstalling pywin32-222:
>       Successfully uninstalled pywin32-222
>
> [prompt]> :: PIP test
>
> [prompt]> pip list 2>nul | findstr pywin32
> pywin32 (223)
>
> [prompt]> :: PyWin32 test
>
> [prompt]> python -c "import win32api as wapi;print(wapi.GetFileVersionInfo(wapi.__file__, \"\\\\\")[\"FileVersionLS\"] >> 16)"
> 223
> ```

Check:

- [[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546) - for more details using *PIP*
- [[SO]: ImportError: No module named win32com.client (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310161/4788546) - for *PyWin32* details

Comment: Interesting approach, more accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: Thank you, @VonC! I remembered that i installed *pywin32* using *pip* but I didn't have the time to test whether upgrade works as well.

Comment: @CristiFati After I upgraded `pip` to 9.0.3, I can do `pip install pywin32` too. I was using an older version which couldn't.

Comment: I was using *9.0.3* (updated the answer). But I've also been able to install *pywin32* using *pip 9.0.1* (*Python 3.5*) - I don't have an older one. Even if your *pip* would have been really old, it doesn't explain it. Were you able to install other packages using the old *pip*? Or could it be that at the time you've tried the *.whl* was not there (published) yet?

Comment: @CristiFati You could be right that the _.whl_ was not there when I did `pip install -U pywin32`. How can I find out? I have lost track of the timestamps of the updates or upgrades earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. The only thing that comes into my mind is contacting the maintainers and asking for that piece of info. But I think that even if v223 wasn't uploaded yet, v222 should have been.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and its [pywin32 package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/PyWin32), but it is out of date.

So a scripting solution as [one described in this article](https://gist.github.com/lukechilds/a83e1d7127b78fef38c2914c4ececc3c) (for other programs, but with a similar idea) is possible. See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8).
If you uncompress the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.16.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.16.2-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and use a **[simplified `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49248983/6309)**, you will have access to 200+ Linux commands, including `awk`, `head`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, `pywin32` happens to be one of those that do not support releases. That is, `https://api.github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/latest` gives "Not Found". Any idea to tackle this issue?