# No module names win32api when running "from pywinauto import application"

Tags: python, pywinauto

any help is appreciated,

I have python 3.7.2 installed. using PyCharm editor I run the following code:

```
from pywinauto import application
```

running that code produces the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/WebAuto/testPyWinAuto.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pywinauto import application
File "C:\Users\<user>\PycharmProjects\WebAuto\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    import win32api  # noqa: E402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what is going on? what to do??

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install *PyWin32* (which is one of *PyWinAuto* dependencies):

```bat
pip install pywin32
```

Check:

- [[GitHub]: pywinauto/pywinauto - Dependencies (if install manually)](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto#dependencies-if-install-manually)
- [[SO]: How to update pywin32 automatically? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499867/4788546)