# How can I handle with Pywin32 and Readthedocs?

Tags: python, documentation, pywin32

I'm trying to publish a documentation project in ReadTheDocs, but I'm having the following mensage:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==305
```

I've tried to remove "pywin32" from my requirements.txt, but it didn't work and the same mensage pops up.

Do you guys have any suggestion how I can handle with that?

Comment: What environment are you working in and publishing from?  Also have you just tried pywin32. instead of pywin32==305 ?

Comment: @WombatPM, I've already tried just pywin32 and it didn't work.
I'm working in a virtual environment (venv) in vscode and I'm trying to publish from Github!

Comment: What is your *OS* and *Python* version? Just launch *Python* from the terminal, and paste the first 2 lines that it outputs, here.

Comment: @CristiFati Oh, sorry! Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files contains the required *.whl*, so there's something else that you're missing. Maybe [\[SO\]: How to update pywin32 automatically? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499867/4788546), or [\[SO\]: Install win32com on MacOs and Linux (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030870/4788546) could help.